# Is there a workaround for Converting from <operationQuery.Data> to Data type?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

### Language:Swift

Hello, I'd like some help in resolving an error being thrown when I try to retrieve data from an Apollo GraphQL request that I'm making. The API in use is the AniList API utilizing GraphQL.

Here's what I've tried:
In my model I'm making the Apollo GraphQL query inside of a search() function. I want to then use the Codable protocol to fill an array of anime objects. Currently it's setup to return just for 1 anime object. I was planning on using this anime list as a data set for TableView later. I wanted to take small steps so my current goal is to at least get the Codable protocol to work and return the response data to an anime Struct object.

The documentation for Apollo shows how to get individual fields but when I try to get the corresponding fields from my response , I don't even have the option.

```swift
func search(){
Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: AnisearchQuery()){ result in
        guard let data = try? result.get().data else { return }
        
    

    var topData:APIResponse?
        do{
            topData = JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data.self)
        }catch{
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the data structures that I've set up as a representation of the JSON data I expect to receive with respect to the hierarchy it is laid out in the response.

```swift
struct APIResponse:Codable{
    let data:data
}

struct data:Codable{
    let Page:page
    let media:media
}

struct media:Codable{
    let animeResults:anime
}
struct anime:Codable{
    var romaji:String
    var english: String
    var native:String
    var episodes:Int
    var duration:Int
    var medium:String
}
```

Here is the error in question.
"Cannot convert value of type 'AnisearchQuery.Data' to expected argument type 'Data'". This is generated by this line of code

`topData = JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data.self)`

For further context , AnisearchQuery.Data is generated in response to the query I created for the codgen.

[Here's what the data would look like in JSON format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Ec1.png)

This is the setup of the query:

```swift
query anisearch($page:Int, $perPage:Int, $search:String){
    Page (page:$page, perPage:$perPage){
        pageInfo {
            total
            currentPage
            lastPage
            hasNextPage
            perPage
        }
        media(search:$search){
            title{
                romaji
                english
                native
            }
            episodes
            duration
            coverImage{
                medium
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Data object in the API.swift file:

```swift
public struct Data: GraphQLSelectionSet {
    public static let possibleTypes: [String] = ["Query"]

    public static var selections: [GraphQLSelection] {
      return [
        GraphQLField("Page", arguments: ["page": GraphQLVariable("page"), "perPage": GraphQLVariable("perPage")], type: .object(Page.selections)),
      ]
    }
```

I'd be open to any alternative methods as to getting this task done or perhaps fixes to the error being thrown.
Many thanks in advance.

### Inefficient Workaround

```swift
var animeCollection:SearchAnimeQuery.Data?
var media:[SearchAnimeQuery.Data.Page.Medium]?
var filteredData:[SearchAnimeQuery.Data.Page.Medium] = []

func loadData(search:String = "") {
        if !search.isEmpty{
            Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: SearchAnimeQuery(search: search)){
                [weak self] result in
                
                //Make Sure ViewController Has not been deallocated
                guard let self = self else{
                    return
                }
                
                /*defer {
                 
                 }*/
                switch result {
                case .success(let graphQLResult):
                    if let animeData = graphQLResult.data {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.animeCollection = animeData
                            self.media = self.animeCollection?.page?.media as! [SearchAnimeQuery.Data.Page.Medium]
                            self.filteredData = self.media!
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let errors = graphQLResult.errors {
                        let message = errors
                            .map { $0.localizedDescription }
                            .joined(separator: "\n")
                        
                        print(message)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `from: data.self)`, change this to `from: data)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for pointing this out. Although it does not affect the error, I realize it's incorrect still I appreciate you pointing that out.

Comment: So the problem is that `result.get().data` doesn't return a value of type `Data` but instead it is of type `AnisearchQuery.Data` whatever that is s

Comment: Creating you own type `data` is asking for confusion down the line with Foundation's `Data` type.  `Response` or something similar would be a far better option.  (Also Swift convention is that all type names are capitalised)

Comment: agreed @flanker. Unfortunately, the  GraphQL response I'm getting gives the data back to me as an AnisearchQuery.Data instead of just Data.

Comment: That doesn't stop you naming your types what you wan though.  You'll need to share  what the `Anisearch` type is and probably how you are generating the query to get any further with a solution.

Comment: @flanker I've edited and included What I wrote in the query file and also the .Data type in the API.swift file.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE Got any workaround for this? I migrated the Apollo library from 0.54 to 1.0.5 which was a huge change. Spend almost 1 week to fix all the compiler issues and now app is crashing on this issue. My whole code base is dependent upon custom DAO(Data Access Object) classes instead of the Apollo generates classes. And for this, I need Data to decode to my model classes. Please let me know if you found any kind of workaround.. Thanks..

Comment: @Hadhi The workaround I found although it was able to do what I wanted , may not be the best solution. I'll edit my post to show the resolution

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE Thanks for the input. But this will not solve my use case. Currently I am on 0.54 version of Apollo SDK which gives the option of getting the response as Swift.Data. I'll stick to it then. And I'll look into some other alternatives for Apollo library. Thanks again for your time..